# Can not mount virtualbox folder in fstab

Tags: mount, virtualbox, fstab

I've just upgraded my VM from Ubuntu server 12.04 to 14.04.

I used to mount my data folder through fstab as follows:

```
datafolder  /mnt/DataFolder  vboxsf  uid=106,gid=113, dir_mode=0770 0 0
```

I had nothing in my `rc.local`, nor anything in my `/etc/modules` (as per some solutions on this site).

When I upgraded to 14.04 this all stopped working. I could manually mount the share using:

```
mount -t vboxsf datafolder /mnt/DataFolder
```

However, on boot I would get an error.

I know this question has been asked a *lot*, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: After boot but before the drive is mounted, does `mount datafolder` work?

Comment: Yes,  it does.  It properly mounts the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after upgrading from Kubuntu (guest) 12.04 to 14.04.  And the solution provided here solves the problem partially. [Virtualbox shared folder mount from fstab fails; works once bootup is complete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365346/virtualbox-shared-folder-mount-from-fstab-fails-works-once-bootup-is-complete)

The solution forces the vboxsf module to be loaded early, before mounting file systems.

It only partially works for me: the error message is still displayed, but strangely, choosing the 'mount manually' (instead of skip mounting) option, and then doing nothing but exiting (Ctrl-D) to continue booting mounts the shared folder, indicating that it works (automatically) during the second try!